# sort C++ - "invalid operator"

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool fun(int i, int j){
    return abs(i - j) != -1;
}

int main(){
    vector <int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), fun);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the comparator 'fun' the programs throws the exception 'invalid operator <'. How can I modify this function to make the program run normally?

Comment: May I ask why you include all these files when you need at most 4 of them?

Comment: @Mahmoud Arafa This condition abs(i - j) != -1 is always equal to true independing on the compared values.:)

Comment: @Borgleader Simply he had no time to include all C++ headers.:)

Comment: What result do you expect if you consider every number smaller than every number?

Answer (score 4):

Your `fun` function does not provide **strict weak ordering**. If `i` and  `j` are equal, it will return true. So you are not following the rules. Your implementation of the standard library responds by throwing an exception.

Comment: I got it, but I tried to modify the function so that it can provide strict weak ordering but I couldn't. Any help?

Comment: @MahmoudArafa Have you tried i < j? If you have different requirements but you can't manage to make them work, you can post your exact efforts in a different question.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I modify this function to make the program run normally?

Assuming you want to sort in ascending order. Just use `operator <`.

```
bool fun(int i, int j)
{
    return i < j;
}
```

Alternatively you could just use the comparator provided by the standard.

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<int>());
```

---

See the link in the comments or the answer provided by @DanielDaranas to understand why your original function doesn't work.